# Content Database showing 0 (zero) site collection after content database attach

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, stsadm, content-database

I have two server farms, Server farm 1 and Server farm 2. Server farm 2 runs SharePoint 2010 Enterprise with SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and Server 1 runs SharePoint 2010 Enterprise with SQL Server 2008 R2 - Express with Advanced Services. I created a backup of my content database of web application running on farm 1 and restored it to sql on server farm 2. I then created a new web application on farm 2 and attached my content db.

Now after I added content db to my new application on farm 2, it shows no site collection and when I try to visit the url I get page doesn't exist error message.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Try using stsadm -o enumsites to check which sites are listed in the specific content database. What method did you use to attach the content db?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jasper.

I used STSADM.exe -o addContentdb -url http://mysite2:80 -DatabaseName WSS_Content_80

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. The reason is because the version numbers for my FARM 1 SQL DB is different from the one on FARM 2.

I upgraded both servers to the same built number and everything worked fine.

Thanks to everyone that replied.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons could be :

The SPTimer job stuck - reset the timers using stsadm execadmsvcjobs command. Cache.ini reset - Not sure about what this file is but following links give some info.

http://sharepoint-pros.com/SPBlog/?p=4

http://sharepointreporter.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/clear-sharepoint-configuration-cache/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is usually seen when you try to attach a copy of a content database to the same farm, and occurs because the GUIDs are the same. Is it possible that your content db on farm 1 was originally migrated from farm 2?